# Taiko - Scope mouseAction to a selector

Tags: getgauge

I have a portion of the page that is a map, and I'd like to do a bunch of `mouseAction`s inside the map.

I'm looking for a way to execute the actions passing coordinates relative to the map, not the whole page:

Instead of:

```
mouseAction('press', {x:0,y:0})
mouseAction('move', {x:0,y:9})
...
```

do:

```
mouseAction($('#map'), 'press', {x:0,y:0})
mouseAction($('#map'), 'move', {x:0,y:9})
...
```

Selenium web driver has something like that: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium%2FWebDriver%2FActionBuilder:move_to

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature in taiko where we can perform the mouse action within a particular area in a page. There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/893) for the same. You can use `mouseAction` with the id once it will be done.